# Get values chosen from Datepicker and store in variable on each selection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-tabbed-activity

How can I get the dates a user has chosen to and from in my datepicker each time. The user will press a button to open the calendar, then chooses the dates from and to. After this is chosen the dates get appended to a TextView. But how can I get the dates each time to store into a variable as I will need to use each date as a value.?

Tab2 class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by hp1 on 21-01-2015.
 */
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    DatePicker pickerDate;
    TextView dateTextView;
    private boolean mAutoHighlight;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);

        Button dateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        dateTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        CheckBox ahl = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.autohighlight_checkbox);
        ahl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                mAutoHighlight = b;
            }
        });

        // Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        Tab2.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.setAutoHighlight(mAutoHighlight);
                dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }

        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = (DatePickerDialog) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");
        if(dpd != null) dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth,int yearEnd, int monthOfYearEnd, int dayOfMonthEnd) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: From- "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year+" To "+dayOfMonthEnd+"/"+(++monthOfYearEnd)+"/"+yearEnd;
        dateTextView.append(date + "\n");
    }
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/autohighlight_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnDateSetListener. something like this

```
 int year,monthofyear,dayofmonth;
  dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            preview.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year+"/")
                    .append(monthOfYear+"/").append(dayOfMonth));
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks but how can I retrieve each individual date using that? Say if the user adds 10 dates how can I have a variable that calculates the days in between on each date appended?